# IF/AND/OR statements

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have applied the conditional formatting in B1 with the formula `=IF(AND(A1<>"APPLE",B1<>""),TRUE,FALSE)`. By this formula, I am telling Excel to highlight the cell B1 in red when B1 has any number but A1 does not have "Apple". Just to simply it what exactly I want is if A1 does not have "Apple" and B1 has any number, highlight B1 in red. The above formula is working fine for me.

But here is my problem. Now what i want is if A1 does not have either "Apple" or "Mango" and B1 has any number, highlight B1 in red. I tried with the formula `=IF(AND(OR(A1<>"APPLE",A1<>"MANGO"),B1<>""),TRUE,FALSE)` This formula is not giving me desired result.

Could you please advice me what changes i need to make to be able to get the desired result.

Comment: Can you try replacing the `OR` with `AND`? Also, if you want to check that `B1` is a *number*, then `ISNUMBER(B1)` is better. At the moment your formula is checking if `B1` is a `null` string or not..

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
AND(A1<>"APPLE",A1<>"MANGO",B1<>"")
```

You can drop the IF because AND already returns TRUE/FALSE